# Getting Argument Error when trying to call form of other controller in another controller show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having 2 models where invoice_details has_many multiple_goods and multiple_goods belongs_to invoice_details.

I am having a condition where when I click on new I have to show the form of multiple_goods as a pop-up in invoice_details_show.

invoice_details/show.html.erb:

```
   <div><%= link_to 'New Person', '#new_person_modal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %></div>

    <%# Bootstrap modal markup. @see: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals %>
    <div class="modal fade" id="new_person_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new person</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%# Render the new person form (passing modal => true to enable remote => true) %>
            <%= render 'multiple_goods/form', modal: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

multiple_goods/_form.html.erb:

```
<%=form_for([:invoice_detail,@multiple_good], html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form' }) do |f| %>
  <% if @multiple_good.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@multiple_good.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this multiple_good from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @multiple_good.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<br/>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description_of_goods1, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">

    <%= f.text_field :description_of_goods1, :class => 'text_field', :required => true,:maxlength => 20, :placeholder => '20 Alpha numeric characters'  %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :quatity1, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">

    <%= f.text_field :quatity1, :class => 'text_field', :required => true,:maxlength => 20, :placeholder => 'Enter quatity'  %>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price_per_unit1, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">

    <%= f.text_field :price_per_unit1, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder => 'Enter price Per unit'  %>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :total_amount1, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">

    <%= f.text_field :total_amount1, :class => 'text_field', readonly: true, :placeholder => 'This field is auto saved'  %>
    </div>
    </div>


 <div class="form-actions2"style="text-align:center">
    <%= f.submit  :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Finally my controller:

```
class MultipleGoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_multiple_good, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @multiple_goods = MultipleGood.all
    respond_with(@multiple_goods)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@multiple_good)
  end

  def new
    @multiple_good = MultipleGood.new
    respond_with(@multiple_good)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.find(params[:invoice_detail_id])
    @multiple_good = @invoice_detail.multiple_goods.create(multiple_good_params)
    redirect_to invoice_detail_path(@invoice_detail)
  end


  def update
    @multiple_good.update(multiple_good_params)
    respond_with(@multiple_good)
  end

  def destroy
    @multiple_good.destroy
    respond_with(@multiple_good)
  end

  private
    def set_multiple_good
      @multiple_good = MultipleGood.find(params[:id])
    end

    def multiple_good_params
      params.require(:multiple_good).permit(:description_of_goods1, :quatity1, :price_per_unit1, :total_amount1)
    end
end
```

My invoice Details controller

```
class InvoiceDetailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice_detail, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @invoice_details = InvoiceDetail.all
    respond_with(@invoice_details)
  end

  def show
 @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @invoice_detail }
    format.pdf { render :layout => false }
  end
  end

  def new
    @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.new
     @invoice_detail_attachment = @invoice_detail.invoice_detail_attachments.build

  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.new(invoice_detail_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice_detail.save
        params[:invoice_detail_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
          @invoice_detail_attachment = @invoice_detail.invoice_detail_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :invoice_detail_id => @invoice_detail.id)
       end
       format.html { redirect_to @invoice_detail, notice: '' }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
     end
   end
 end

  def update
    @invoice_detail.update(invoice_detail_params)
    if @invoice_detail.save
        params[:invoice_detail_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
          @invoice_detail_attachment = @invoice_detail.invoice_detail_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :invoice_detail_id => @invoice_detail.id)
       end
    redirect_to invoice_details_path
  end
end


  def destroy
    @invoice_detail.destroy
  redirect_to invoice_details_path
  end
  def download
  require 'zip/zip'
  require 'zip/zipfilesystem'
  @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.find(params[:invoice_id])

  t = Tempfile.new('tmp-zip-' + request.remote_ip)
  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
    @invoice_detail.invoice_detail_attachments.each do |file|
      zos.put_next_entry(file.invoice_detail)
      zos.print IO.read(file.avatar.path)     
    end
  end

  send_file t.path, :type => "application/zip", :filename => "#{@invoice_detail.invoice_number}.zip"

  t.close
end



  private
    def set_invoice_detail
      @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.find(params[:id])
    end

    def invoice_detail_params
      params.require(:invoice_detail).permit(:avatar,:attachment,:invoice_number, :supplier_name, :invoice_date, :invoice_due_date, :description_of_goods, :quatity, :price_per_unit, :total_amount, :mode_of_payment, :status, :shipping_country, :sl_no, :containers, :net_weight, :bl_number, :bl_date, :insurance_provider, :insurance_amount, :insurance_status, :coo_payment, :farworder, :farworder_inv_amt_doller, :farworder_inv_amt_idr, :payment_status_to_farworder,:final_amount )
    end
end
```

When I am running on server, i am getting error as :

**ArgumentError in InvoiceDetails#show**

*First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty*

Comment: Show us `InvoiceDetailsController` please.

Comment: Tanks for reply Added InvoiceDetailsController please go through it

Comment: Added InvoiceDetailsController please check it . –  Зелёный

Comment: you're missing a definition for @multiple_good in your InvoiceDetails controller which is rendering the form.

Comment: even i was getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Your action show in InvoiceDetailsController doesn't include a new multiple_goods for the _form, you should take into account that render in views only render a view doesn't pass throught another action.

```
def show
 @invoice_detail = InvoiceDetail.find(params[:id])
 @multiple_good = MultipleGood.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @invoice_detail }
    format.pdf { render :layout => false }
  end
  end
```

Comment: getting the same issues eve i did that change Thanks for reply @ppascualv

Comment: I made an error please put multiple_good instead of multiple_goods

Comment: its showing error like 

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"multiple_goods", :format=>nil, :id=>"10"} missing required keys: [:invoice_detail_id]

Comment: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in InvoiceDetails#show